# Deleting rows based on multiple values in another table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

This statement is returning error 00920- invalid relational operator.

I am sure it is my syntax, but I am not seeing it.  If anycode could look it over and point me to getting it right, I would appreciate it.

Thank you

```
DELETE FROM TABLE15 p

  WHERE (p.item_id, p.product_id) IN

           (SELECT S.item_id, S.product_id )

              FROM TABLE14 S);
```

Comment: The closing brace at the end of the select row is a typo?

Comment: P.S., I'm voting to close as this is essentially a bug in your code; and not really useful to future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your brackets are dodgy...

```
DELETE FROM TABLE15 p
  WHERE (p.item_id, p.product_id) IN
           (SELECT S.item_id, S.product_id
              FROM TABLE14 S
                   );
```

You need to remove the additional one. The error is caused by `in` not being parsed correctly due to the extra bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM table15 p
WHERE  ( p.item_id IN (SELECT S.item_id
                       FROM   table14 S) )
        OR (( p.product_id IN (SELECT S.product_id
                               FROM   table14 S) ));
```

Comment: In this case rows would be deleted based on any of the individual values of `item_id` and `product_id`, but the intent of the question is to delete based on the existing combinations of item_id and product_id.  I won't downvote it as it's a fair attempt, but I don't think it does what the OP intended.